# Auto Login Python support needed

Tags: python, authentication, auto

i am into my first-week learning python and am looking to automate login to a website. I can get to the website and get the username and password entered but the issue is the submit/login button. I have tried to use the same as the username and password using the below but it doesn't find this id, i am using the inspect tool on chrome to find the ids as i did for the username and password.

```
driver.find_element_by_id('GSubmitButtton-8f6df913-9588-4480-9944-538b785b8ece').click()
```

Error message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="GSubmitButtton-8f6df913-9588-4480-9944-538b785b8ece"]"}

driver.find_element_by_id('GSubmitButtton-8f6df913-9588-4480-9944-538b785b8ece').click()
```

Login URL = https://www.gamma-portal.com/login.jspa

Comment: Please edit your post to include the login URL

Comment: Sorry i have just done that now

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use XPath to locate the login button?

You could find this by:

1. Right clicking
   on the log in button,
2. Clicking inspect from the dropdown,
3. Right
   click on the button element,
4. Select copy,
5. Copy XPath

Then enter the result into this line (replace the ###)

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("###").click()`

[Some documentation for this method here!](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Comment: Thanks for the help I have just given this a go with no luck still getting an error message

Comment: Looks like the ID is generated new for each visit. Try the following:
`driver.findElement(By.css("button[value^='GSubmitButton']"))`

This is using a CSS selector to locate the button with a value starting with GSubmitButton.